# Carbon Date error On new setup laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, web, php-carbon

I have setup a `laravel 5.3` new setup with `mongodb` working fine but at the time of password reset submit form i am getting error.

Exception in `Carbon.php` line 221: `DateTime::__construct()` expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we get the code you use to reset password?

Comment: $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

Comment: from here that error is coming And i unable to get actual defination of function written in these lines ??

Comment: What are you sending as `inputs` ?

Comment: email,password_confirmation,password and token

Comment: @prateekkathal but i got solution don't know right or wrong

Comment: @prateekkathal added this to kernel.php providers array >>Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,

Comment: You need to add it to app.php, not kernel.php and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {

        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.

        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );


        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->forceFill([
            'password' => bcrypt($password),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
        ])->save();

        $this->guard()->login($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse($response)
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

I am using this laravel default code

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to `config/app.php` solves the problem:

```
Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
```